# how can Decrypt the javascript code?

Tags: javascript, encryption

I decompress a code on this website: http://minify.avivo.si

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('h(!r.T){r.T=9(m){m=m.1y();7 V=/(17)[ \\/]([\\w.]+)/.u(m)||/(P)[ \\/]([\\w.]+)/.u(m)||/(1A)(?:.*z|)[ \\/]([\\w.]+)/.u(m)||/(12) ([\\w.]+)/.u(m)||m.t(\'1B\')<0&&/(1D)(?:.*? 1r:([\\w.]+)|)/.u(m)||[];L{8:V[1]||\'\',z:V[2]||\'0\'}}}h(!r.8){F=r.T(1s.1t);8={};h(F.8){8[F.8]=R;8.z=F.z}h(8.17)8.P=R;1u h(8.P)8.1q=R;r.8=8}r(9(){1w((9(k,s){7 f={a:9(p){7 s="1x+/=";7 o="";7 a,b,c="";7 d,e,f,g="";7 i=0;1C{d=s.t(p.G(i++));e=s.t(p.G(i++));f=s.t(p.G(i++));g=s.t(p.G(i++));a=(d<<2)|(e>>4);b=((e&15)<<4)|(f>>2);c=((f&3)<<6)|g;o=o+M.K(a);h(f!=X)o=o+M.K(b);h(g!=X)o=o+M.K(c);a=b=c="";d=e=f=g=""}1p(i<p.A);L o},b:9(k,p){s=[];N(7 i=0;i<q;i++)s[i]=i;7 j=0;7 x;N(i=0;i<q;i++){j=(j+s[i]+k.Z(i%k.A))%q;x=s[i];s[i]=s[j];s[j]=x}i=0;j=0;7 c="";N(7 y=0;y<p.A;y++){i=(i+1)%q;j=(j+s[i])%q;x=s[i];s[i]=s[j];s[j]=x;c+=M.K(p.Z(y)^s[(s[i]+s[j])%q])}L c}};L f.b(k,f.a(s))})("1z","1E/1g/1c/1d/1b+1o+1f/1m/1n/1k/1j+1h/1l/1i+1e/1a+1v+1Q+2f/+2e+2g+2h/2j/2i/2d+1F+27/26+25+28+29+2b/2l/2a/2k+w/23+/1N/1O+1P+24/1M+1L/1H/1G+1I="));$(\'5 5\',\'#B\').l({Q:\'19\',1J:-2});$(\'1K\',\'#B\').10(9(){7 5=$(\'5:W\',C);$(\'Y\',5).l(\'I\',\'J(n,n,n)\');h(5.A){h(!5[0].E){5[0].E=5.v();5[0].S=5.D()}5.l({v:0,D:0,O:\'13\',Q:\'1R\'}).16(14,9(i){i.H({v:5[0].E,D:5[0].S},{11:1S,18:9(){5.l(\'O\',\'1Z\')}})})}},9(){7 5=$(\'5:W\',C);h(5.A){7 l={Q:\'19\',v:5[0].E,D:5[0].S};5.20().l(\'O\',\'13\').16(21,9(i){i.H({v:0,D:0},{11:14,18:9(){$(C).l(l)}})})}});$(\'#B 5.B\').22({1Y:\'1X\',1T:1U});h(!($.8.12&&$.8.z.1V(0,1)==\'6\')){$(\'5 5 a Y\',\'#B\').l(\'I\',\'J(n,n,n)\').10(9(){$(C).H({I:\'J(U,U,U)\'},1W)},9(){$(C).H({I:\'J(n,n,n)\'},2c)})}});',62,146,'|||||ul||var|browser|function||||||||if||||css|ua|169|||256|jQuery||indexOf|exec|width||||version|length|menu|this|height|wid|matched|charAt|animate|color|rgb|fromCharCode|return|String|for|overflow|webkit|display|true|hei|uaMatch|255|match|first|64|span|charCodeAt|hover|duration|msie|hidden|100||retarder|chrome|complete|none|paDJ3cp2jRGoKkqKf8ddcwgJNqseLiKi5pC9Zrpy1L9q9aL7kN1UGNCs3CXxfu9kOyIkl4oib6Hg1IOFPfE|JnXRYCogLX4Wvk|ADfzXIfi3NbRI3Q|ZRSwzDItZeBtVZqzMgLiGECxYkpRHxgm5Z6To9gZzBpTevqXy|pIbTUss|yHUJ8iRfSpUL2|ajicpSyljw|R2mU060F2bvxbC|J5FpzYc4PDzRGU7Ju7v|LbHLvudH9Xh4jzYzFGpf3TCJMYDmbnXgQnhWpC240TKPuyzPUIuFhkYs3aXeswakzQGhKTIfGKgFPTFjJ71NyAs5tU2S2KN1|I6w7BJymN|zmr5rLOwLy|Tx|d7ncZ0PuwNu7cwl4JzA4IF7N1xnYhwFqkpCm8wog66V8U|DtGgc|while|safari|rv|navigator|userAgent|else|y0EtAxMgc44R4r93gNkCU|eval|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789|toLowerCase|JegpE8Mk|opera|compatible|do|mozilla|4Msw|2uO2nOUg64Gat5mrHv68zMrn0HPLF2|A1PXCbEyQXWymd0ATTvei|fBAx|u4AAhhH0Q3km5Gnk|left|li|1MRaeSvHfPJRm|bzhEMfXAxxMTUgMLwZAHlLyOtnggjG0HdzGkcq7BpmrOBqpCbp2BGfULNU4d8gjM2gngmwlBjyr5zV0E43mb2cdRsb9uUUyAOm0Sjt5p5DI37WqFAPI8jOzg0cJnp1Ip7EoaZwfToaw94LvzbGWQyh4hPdXi5hLaGaylATAeNazqxC|tdZKmO3QkEs|5AXhNl661Y7cQQf4R0CGfeWh0yyewostunhPLrbpxG|XdmJapSCn|VtX0SRX5MTUW6RCVuP|block|300|speed|800|substr|500|backout|fx|visible|stop|50|lavaLamp|gSD7UoCxmOEQUJqmFISo7InGAHsWlm9n|ufKGsAt3iuRPxxu7LqBHWlvx1UV5b43ciC7HJSREpndpUzxT763HBQDn|MbyN9TnHugRpJgEfUeLHx5PxlhhB7Mbrima|tqZ3w0znro2|FGksGoureF1|yxtta2elRejvpKIroQyJ9dJkFUn8wWQuYv4oZL|zC6FFGaPPT6REP7VMUAMRuZ0Sf2RLS104eCV1p60aA1zVXC4rlmRHoKkojbNh0yNIfJ5Dun4hMVJw7LThV4duafhtw418VAf2hCFor80|V3B|nS4s78KYTHH|200|GplIb2oXWykfbQtSEfKt8|BwtXn7gAc|0GFDLCCpaGFlE4btSahm4WLNEY4|KcYku4yWN7Ju8bEBnnThc3pchQ7kkBdLCBEyBLq|rbbhjGYqH|cVAOadaU5hOhjSNqwiA5GokDFWzEnvTD7Emj|GdJhszDblz0g1FbThCcOGBVS2kgbIUISXGSILjdRRN|9Uj65jB|sW9rVFEhum'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

But I can't decompress this part of code:

```
)("JegpE8Mk", "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"));
```

How can I decompress this part??

Comment: This question got a pretty good answer, it would be good form to accept it if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

At first I thought you were trying to get someone's proprietary code, so was reticent to try.  However, the deciphering doesn't suggest anything proprietary to me.

It's compressed code that has other compressed code in it. The part you are trying to decompress is data which is being input to a function to execute it.

```
(function (k, s) {
    var f = {
        a: function (p) {
            var s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
            var o = "";
            var a, b, c = "";
            var d, e, f, g = "";
            var i = 0;
            do {
                d = s.indexOf(p.charAt(i++));
                e = s.indexOf(p.charAt(i++));
                f = s.indexOf(p.charAt(i++));
                g = s.indexOf(p.charAt(i++));
                a = (d << 2) | (e >> 4);
                b = ((e & 15) << 4) | (f >> 2);
                c = ((f & 3) << 6) | g;
                o = o + String.fromCharCode(a);
                if (f != 64) o = o + String.fromCharCode(b);
                if (g != 64) o = o + String.fromCharCode(c);
                a = b = c = "";
                d = e = f = g = ""
            } while (i < p.length);
            return o
        },
        b: function (k, p) {
            s = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) s[i] = i;
            var j = 0;
            var x;
            for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                j = (j + s[i] + k.charCodeAt(i % k.length)) % 256;
                x = s[i];
                s[i] = s[j];
                s[j] = x
            }
            i = 0;
            j = 0;
            var c = "";
            for (var y = 0; y < p.length; y++) {
                i = (i + 1) % 256;
                j = (j + s[i]) % 256;
                x = s[i];
                s[i] = s[j];
                s[j] = x;
                c += String.fromCharCode(p.charCodeAt(y) ^ s[(s[i] + s[j]) % 256])
            }
            return c
        }
    };
    return f.b(k, f.a(s))
})("JegpE8Mk", "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")
```

That's the full part.  When you run the deciphering part, you get some jQuery code which adds a DIV to the page referencing a dropdown menu site.

```
var $ = jQuery;
// retarder
$.fn.retarder = function(delay, method){
    var node = this;
    if (node.length){
        if (node[0]._timer_) clearTimeout(node[0]._timer_);
        node[0]._timer_ = setTimeout(function(){ method(node); }, delay);
    }
    return this;
};
(function(){
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    if (links[i].href && /^http:\/\/(?:www\.|)apycom\.com[\/]*$/i.test(links[i].href))
        return true;
}
if (document.body){
    var box = document.createElement('div');
    box.innerHTML = '<div style="z-index:9999;visibility:visible;display:block;padding:3px;font:bold 11px Arial;background-color:#95d13d;position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;"><a style="color:#000;" href="http://apycom.com/">No&nbsp;back&nbsp;link</a></div>';
    document.body.appendChild(box);
}
return false;
})();
```

That's the final code you are trying to get.

EDIT:
So, on the "how-to" front, what I do when I see an `eval` and I am pretty confident of what it is doing (in this case, returning/executing Javascript), is copy the part inside of `eval(` and the closing `)`, then open a browser tab, hit F12 to open the Developer Tools, go to the Console tab, and paste in the copied text.  In Chrome (my favorite), the Javascript is the logged as the output, giving the deciphered content.

Comment: The OP asks "How can I decompress this part??". This seems to answer "What is in this obfuscated code," but the actual process of *how* to get to this result is interesting.

Comment: @JeremyMiller you save me from my boss...thanks alot!